# Spring boot Embedded Tomcat "application/json" post request restriction to 10KB

Tags: json, rest, tomcat, post, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot embedded tomcat for publishing rest service.

Spring boot version used latest "1.3.6.RELEASE"

I have requirement to limit the application/json post request size to 10KB.

Tired this solution but not working,
[Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot)

Please help.

Thanks,
Arun.

Comment: Don't know if it suits you, but you can configure it in Tomcat: see `maxPostSize` parameter in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Im using embedded tomcat tried setting this but not working,  
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                (connector) -> {
                    connector.setMaxPostSize(10000); // 10 KB
                }
            );
        }
    };
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Configuring the max post size only applies to requests with a `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. There's no mechanism available out of the box in Tomcat to limit the size of a request body for requests with any other content type so you'll have to write some code.

You could limit the content length using a filter. For example, adding the following class to your Spring Boot application will reject an request with a `Content-Type` that is compatible with `application/json` and a `Content-Length` over 10000:

```
@Component
static class ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isApplicationJson(request) && request.getContentLengthLong() > 10000) {
            throw new IOException("Request content exceeded limit of 10000 bytes");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isApplicationJson(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(MediaType
                .parseMediaType(httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE))));
    }

}
```

Note that this filter won't reject requests without a `Content-Length` header that exceed 10000 bytes, for example one that uses chunked encoding.

Comment: Thanks Andy. It works fine. If there is no Content-Length header then the value of request.getContentLength() or request.getContentLengthLong() will be zero? Can we use that for validation?

Comment: Instead of Zero it should be -1

Comment: If the request has no `Content-Length` header, one can wrap the `ServletRequest` into one that returns a `LimitedSizeInputStream` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30072143/11748454).