# Limit size of http application/json request body in Spring, tomcat

Tags: java, json, spring, http, tomcat

I want to limit the size of accepted application/json http request bodys. So that it is not possible to send multiple megabytes of json to my application, which are then processed and make my app run for a long time.

I've read here that there is no out of the box solution to do this.
 [Spring boot Embedded Tomcat "application/json" post request restriction to 10KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607159/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-application-json-post-request-restriction-to-10kb)

Is there another solution beside implementing something myself.
For me this seems like a very common use-case and I can't believe that there is no general solution for this, because this is a very easily exploitable security issue.

Comment: In my opinion the refereced question does not answer this question. There is no default limit. I tried requests with roughly 20 MB and they were accepted.

I also configured the server.tomcat.max-http-post-size property from spring - and it did not work. Though I can try configuring it directly in the tomcat settings

Answer (score 2):

there is no out of the box solution, but simplest way would be to write a filter to check request length, something like this

```
@Component
static class ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isApplicationJson(request) && request.getContentLengthLong() > 10000) {
            throw new IOException("Request content exceeded limit of 10000 bytes");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isApplicationJson(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(MediaType
                .parseMediaType(httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for post requests in spring boot :

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size
```

Comment: `max-http-form-post-size` is the Spring Boot 2.x equivalent of `max-http-post-size` (which didn't work for the OP). The property was renamed to stress out that it **only** applies to content of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.