# How can I limit the body of a application/octet-stream request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm developing a service that will receive a file through an HTTP Post request. The file is sent by the request body with a `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header. I want to limit the request body to 10MB. Here's a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of my goal:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("save")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> save(@RequestBody byte[] data) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("size", data.length));
    }
}
```

To test my endpoint I tried this `curl` command:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary "@my_big_binary_file.whatever" http://localhost:8080/save
```

I tried to set the following properties, but with no success:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=10MB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=10MB
```

So, my question is: I'm going have multiple requests like this on my service. How can I limit the size of all of them to 10MB? Also, and I think it's related: what's the purpose of these two properties? Isn't it what I was expecting?

Tested using Java 17 on Spring Boot [2.7.9](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.9&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,devtools) and [3.0.4](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,devtools)

---

PS.: I know there's a way to limit `multipart/form-data` requests using the properties below. That works just fine. But it's not what I need.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit size of http application/json request body in Spring, tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118627/limit-size-of-http-application-json-request-body-in-spring-tomcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the response that [Chin Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57719/chin-huang) inserted is valid! You would need to change it only a little bit to limit octet-stream only.

It would be almost like that:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isApplicationOctet(request) && request.getContentLengthLong() > 10000) {
            throw new IOException("Request content exceeded limit of 10000 bytes");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isApplicationOctet(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.isCompatibleWith(MediaType
                .parseMediaType(httpRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE))));
    }
}
```

This solution is based on [Chin Huang answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118627/limit-size-of-http-application-json-request-body-in-spring-tomcat), just adjusting the datatype.