Limiting the size of a RequestBody
I have following controller. Which takes a post request and process as required.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        
        if (loginRequest.getUsername().length() < 5 || loginRequest.getUsername().length() > 10) {
            return "Username must be between 5 to 10 character.";
        }
        ...
        return "This is the login response.";
    }

}

LoginRequest.java
public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }
    ...
}

As seen above, the parameter are passed as HTTP request body @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest
The issue is currently, someone can send malicious requests with random large amount of data. For e.g. a username of 5000 characters. Though the authentication would fail but still multiple such request can impact the performance of the server, and makes it vulnerable to DoS attacks.
Hence, I want to enforce a size validation on application level over the incoming request body. E.g. it shouldn’t be more than 10mb etc. However, I am not sure, how to do it.
A similar question is here, however i am not using jboss and also changing server configurations isnt an option and looking to limit or resolve it on application level. Also, my request isnt a form multipart but rather JSON sent as request body.

@ChinHuang The referenced answer is for multipart requests and doesn't apply to a JSON being sent as the RequestBody of a request.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118627/limit-size-of-http-application-json-request-body-in-spring-tomcat

As you mentioned, limiting the request size is an effective strategy to prevent resource exhaustion caused by large requests. This can be achieved by validating the overall request size rather than individual field sizes. Here's an example implementation using the '@MaxByteLength' annotation:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @MaxByteLength(value = 1024 * 1024 * 10) // 10 MB Limit (adjust as needed)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        // Your code here...

    }
}

The @MaxByteLength annotation conveniently handles request size validation. It's a clean, simple, and efficient approach.
To import this annotation, use either:
From JAVAX:
import javax.validation.constraints.MaxByteLength;

From JAKARTA:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.MaxByteLength;

I hope this helps!
From Brazil.

I am unable to resolve MaxByteLength annotation in jakarta.validation.constraints

@Nullpointer this answer seems wrong, @MaxByteLength does not seem to exist either in javax or jakarta.

Your question as it's phrased might provide you with answers that probably won't fix your issue as it seems to be security related.
Let's see the following part of your question

The issue is currently, someone can send malicious requests with
random large amount of data. For e.g. a username of 5000 characters.
Though the authentication would fail but still multiple such request
can impact the performance of the server, and makes it vulnerable to
DoS attacks. Hence, I want to enforce a size validation on application
level over the incoming request body

Since your question is related with spring boot, in spring boot we have 1 server (e.g. Tomcat) deployed that hosts 1 application. If you make such validation on application level and inside your code as you suggest, this would mean that the server hosting your application would have already accepted the message and would already be prone to Dos attacks. So there is no reason (at least as described in question) for you to make such implementation in your application code.
The default server if not defined otherwise for spring-boot is tomcat. Tomcat already has thought about Dos attacks and has several mechanisms in place for such actions, such as maxPostSize & maxSwallowSize configurations in connector.
According to the doc this can also be configured with a property in your application.yaml for spring-boot to transfer those configurations to tomcat when deployed.

server.tomcat.max-swallow-size , Maximum amount of request body to
swallow, default: 2MB
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size Maximum size of the form
content in any HTTP post request, default: 2MB

Jetty and Undertow which are alternatives of tomcat if configured as servers in spring-boot also provide a similar set of properties for the same reason.

Thanks, but what i understand from here and few other places is that those properties only affect content of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and not JSON body, as its the case with me.

Here's an alternative. I believe you're using Spring Boot, so I decided to implement it using Spring Boot.
In Spring, we can create a filter for requests, which allows us to work with the request before it even enters the application's processing flow.
This is widely used for authentication, for example, where you validate a token sent in the request header before starting processing. It can be a JWT token or something similar. So, I implemented a filter that validates the request size.
In this example, I'm using Jakarta, but if your implementation depends on Javax, just change jakarta to javax in the import statement.
RequestFilter, responsible for validating the request body size:
import jakarta.servlet.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomRequestFilter implements Filter {

    public static final long MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE_IN_MB = 10;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            final ServletRequest servletRequest,
            final ServletResponse servletResponse,
            final FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final long requestBodySize = servletRequest.getContentLengthLong();
        if (requestBodySize > MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE_IN_MB * 1024 * 1024)
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    String.format(
                            "Request body size exceeds the limit of %d MB",
                            MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE_IN_MB
                    )
            );

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

}

RequestFilterConfig, responsible for configuring the RequestFilter bean in the application:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RequestFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomRequestFilter customRequestFilter() {
        return new CustomRequestFilter();
    }

}

I hope this helps!
From Brazil.
