# How to get Response code and Response body , When a filter is invoked and throws exception in spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-filter

```
I am using Swagger to get response of PUT() method. I have created a filter to limit request body size to 10000kb in my Spring boot Application. When I send request os size greater than 10000kb, i get swagger response as below.
Response Body :"no content" 
Response code: 500
```

I referred below link 
[Spring boot Embedded Tomcat "application/json" post request restriction to 10KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607159/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-application-json-post-request-restriction-to-10kb)

I used below to register the filter..

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean loginRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ApplicationJsonRequestSizeLimitFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/*"));
        return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

How can i get status code, and custom message thrown by filter in response body.

Comment: @ruper kumar any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html#value--)

Here is an example how that would look like.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionResolver{

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Invalid request type")
@ExceptionHandler(value = SomeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<CustomError> handleSomeException(HttpServletRequest request, SomeException e){
    CustomError error = new CustomError();
    error.setMessage("Very large file");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(error);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail , like how we will get request object here, And how to register this

Comment: You can simply pass the request as paramter.

Comment: Here is better explanation on how to use it.
https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice

Comment: @Nikola Ivanov  ControllerAdvice works only after the filter chain had been finished, with Filters you do not get to use ControllerAdvice